# Tiled Editor Change where tile snaps to grid

Tags: tiled

[image: Tile snaps to grid on left]

As you can see the tile snaps to the grid on the left I need to move it to the right So that the ramp is in the Grid on the left. So Black square should be in the grid and ramp on the left of it

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to offset individual tiles, but there are two ways to work around this:

1. You could split up the tile such that you have two pieces that match with your grid size. Then you would place these next to each other on the map.
2. Alternatively, you could keep your tiles as-is, but add this wider tile (and probably the one to the right of it as well) to their own tileset. On the tileset you can set a "Drawing Offset", which is an offset applied when rendering tiles from that tileset. You can use it to shift these tiles a bit to the left, such that they will align to the grid the way you want.